# Accessing environmental variables on rundeck node

Tags: unix, rundeck

This is a two-part question. I am running a script using rundeck that depends on access to environmental variables system-wide on the node I'm executing the script on that I have set in /etc/environment.

First, how do I get rundeck to ingest the system environment? I can't find any option in rundeck to do this.

Second, why doesn't this happen by default? I'm under the impression that rundeck works through ssh; shouldn't the system environment be loaded every time it logs in to the node?

Answer (score 1):

> First, how do I get rundeck to ingest the system environment? I can't
>   find any option in rundeck to do this.

I succeeded to perform this by adding the following lines to:

```
set -a
. /etc/environment
. /etc/profile
```

1) put those lines into the file: /etc/rundeck/profile

2) put those lines into a script step

Remark: I'm using only script steps in my rundeck and I'm always put this lines in the first line of the script step:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

> Second, why doesn't this happen by default? I'm under the impression
>   that rundeck works through ssh; shouldn't the system environment be
>   loaded every time it logs in to the node?

I think that you need to cinfigre something in the ssh_config file.
check this link: [Rundeck not setting up environment variable for remote execution with different ssh port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315968/rundeck-not-setting-up-environment-variable-for-remote-execution-with-different)