# Setting and accessing environmental variable used by rundeck

Tags: environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04, rundeck

I have Rundeck 2.10.6-1 installed on a Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS server and would like to set environmental variables just for rundeck. Rundeck itself is functioning normally.

I am able to set the environmental variables in /etc/environment for system-wide availability, but I'd like them to be accessible only by the rundeck session. One of them is SQLCMDPASSWORD, a plain text password, utilized by SQLCMD, so I'd like tighter access. We ended up using this approach for PSQL as well.

I have the rundeck $HOME directory identified as /var/lib/rundeck and the $USER name confirmed as 'rundeck'.

I find that adding environmental variables to .bashrc, .bash_profile, or .profile in that directory are not utilized by 'rundeck' as confirmed with a commandline job executing only 'printenv'. When logged in to the server as 'rundeck' I see the variables.

Am I setting these in right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no, those variables were not set in the correct place. Here's why...

There were some clues in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855378/accessing-environmental-variables-on-rundeck-node) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315968/rundeck-not-setting-up-environment-variable-for-remote-execution-with-different?noredirect=1&lq=1) but neither was sufficient. Applications have their environmental variables set in their profile, and for rundeck that would be

```
$ more /etc/rundeck/profile
```

Second clue is from the head of that file which, loosely quoted, indicates

> NOTE: DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE. It will be replaced when the package is upgraded and your changes will not be saved. To override variables in this file, you can instead create a file at: /etc/default/rundeckd

So, I created that default file and set my environmental variables by adding the following content

```
export SQLCMDUSER=batman
export SQLCMDPASSWORD='secret_bat_password'
```

Now it works as intended.

Comment: To further expand on that, deb-based installations will use /etc/default/rundeckd . rpm-based ones will use /etc/sysconfig/rundeckd to override the variables set on /etc/rundeck/profile.